# SQL query not working due to error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to use a internal SQL command to query a table and use the result to query another but am getting the following problem

"Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Must declare the scalar variable "@ListofPropIDs"."

Any help would be appreciated

```
DECLARE @ListofPropIDs TABLE(IDs VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO         @ListofPropIDs 
SELECT              Id 
FROM                Property
WHERE               CreatedBy = 'oliver@test.co.uk' 

SELECT          
    COUNT           (Digits)
    FROM            dbo.CallInfo
    WHERE           Digits = @ListofPropIDs; 

GO
```

Comment: here you @ListofPropIDs declared this one as table and calling it as column

Comment: how do i fix it so it calls each value out of the table. In c# i would do a foreach statement so that it queried each value in the table and give a total count of all them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without knowing what you want to achieve, something like this should work but may not be correct:

```
DECLARE @ListofPropIDs TABLE(IDs VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO         @ListofPropIDs 
SELECT              Id 
FROM                Property
WHERE               CreatedBy = 'oliver@test.co.uk' 

SELECT          
    COUNT           (Digits)
    FROM            dbo.CallInfo
    WHERE           Digits in (SELECT IDs FROM @ListofPropIDs)
```

Your original query is trying to use a table variable as part of a where clause as if it where a column which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @ListofPropIDs TABLE(IDs VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO         @ListofPropIDs 
SELECT              Id 
FROM                Property
WHERE               CreatedBy = 'oliver@test.co.uk' 

SELECT          
    COUNT           (Digits)
    FROM            dbo.CallInfo C
    INNER JOIN @ListofPropIDs s
    on s.IDs = c.Digits
```

Answer (score 0):

@ListofPropIDs is a table and you're using it like a Value.

use :

```
SELECT          
    COUNT           (Digits)
    FROM            dbo.CallInfo
    WHERE           Digits IN ( SELECT IDs from @ListofPropIDs)

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a table as where condition value

Instead you can use [SQL: IN Condition](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php)

```
SELECT          COUNT (Digits)
FROM            dbo.CallInfo
WHERE           Digits IN (Select Id  From  @ListofPropIDs)
```

Or use [Inner Join](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
  SELECT          COUNT (Digits)
  FROM            dbo.CallInfo C
                  Inner Join @ListofPropIDs T On T.Id=C.Digits
```